# Gorm range query using map condition

Tags: go-gorm

Can I pass in a map in gorm to support range query for numeric or time based values? Like, if I have a column named mileage, make `WHERE mileage BETWEEN 100 AND 200` into a map and let gorm do `db.Where(map).Find(&cars)`

Answer (score 1):

**This can't be done with map conditions.**

So the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions) for map conditions does not mention how this could be done, but it doesn't explicitly say it's not supported. Unfortunately, looking at the code of `DB.Where` on gorm, it's clear when building the query conditions, there's only support for either = or IN. The related function that processes the Where argument into clauses is `BuildCondtion`: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/statement.go#L281

When I encountered the situation where I wanted to add a range query dynamically, what I did was **build my own clause.Expression array** and pass THAT to `Where`:

```golang
conds := make([]clause.Expression, 0, 4)
// I couldn't find a BETWEEN clause explicitly, so doing gte and lte instead:
conds = append(conds, clause.Gte{Column: key, Value: mileage.Min})
conds = append(conds, clause.Lte{Column: key, Value: mileage.Max})

db.Where(clause.Where{Exprs: conds}).Find(&cars)
```